# "Simple" jQuery traversal difficulty given multiple identical ID's (I know)

Tags: jquery, traversal

This should be simple but my mind has gone blank. Given I want to update the `input#mirror-field` when the input just above it in the markup changes - how can I target that "next" ID?

Given (don't ask!) there are other inputs with the same ID on the page.

So in simple terms, I want to traverse to only the *next* input with that ID, and no others.

```
<div class="controls">
 <input type="text" class="form_datetime" value="11/09/16">
 <input type="hidden" id="mirror_field" name="nextcontact" value="07/04/17">
 <input type="hidden" name="currentnextcontact" value="2016-09-11">
</div>
```

Current jQuery:

```
 $(".form_datetime").change(function() {
    var $value = $(this).val();
    $('#mirror_field').val($value); //Which I assume will affect all the #mirror_field inputs on the page (I know, I know)
 });
```

Comment: I suppose the first question needs to be *why* you are duplicating IDs

Comment: Mate, did you see the multiple sardonic "I know's" in the question? It's not my code, and sorting that out will take extra time :)

Comment: FYI, [`ID` must be unique in a page.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @Alex Are you serious?

Comment: Yes. Please read its specific.

Comment: @Alex I know this already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function:

```
$(".form_datetime").change(function() {
    var $value = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('#mirror_field').val($value);
    // This will select the "mirror_field" element that are siblings
    // of the "form_datetime" element that just changed.
});
```

Comment: ...yes I wasn't sure about next() either haha, let me test siblings ;)

Comment: @mayersdesign sorry with the initial "next()" answer, I got confused for a while about how it works :)

Comment: Thanks very much .siblings() cracked it. I appreciate your time. Plus you understood that I KNOW ID's are supposed to be unique, so that makes you unique for this question apparently! :)

Comment: @mayersdesign no problem, I've dealt with non-unique IDs myself, so I know how it feels haha, good luck! :D